# Does the degree to which events are independent increase as the number of events increase?

Tags: probability, independence, distributions

I'm considering a problem of independence of events. Specifically, I am considering whether events are more independent the greater the number of events.

Two examples might help.

Example 1:
There are 6 clients in a particularly concentrated financial market and we are considering the probability that a clients' losses exceed a particular amount x. Given their are only 6 clients in this market, we cannot say that the probability of one client reporting a loss greater than x is independent of another client's similarly defined probability (zero-sum game in this case). Therefore, these events are neither mutually or pairwise independent.

Example 2:
Now consider a market that has a more diverse pool of clients. The events are similarly defined as above, as is the probability of one client reporting a loss of greater than an amount x. Does the fact that there are more clients in this market mean that the events are *more* independent?

Note: I don't think the above is true, but I need to disprove it theoretically/mathematically (or prove it theoretically/mathematically if it does hold)

Comment: There are no _degrees_ of independence in _probability theory:_ either two events (or random variables) are independent, or they are not. Statistical practice might be different.

Comment: Yes I agree @DilipSarwate, it was someone else that was arguing that and I am trying to think of the best way to show it's not correct

Comment: There are degrees of _correlation_ and perhaps that is what was mean instead of independence?